# error: ____ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i try to compile my publishJoints code i keep getting errors saying out of scope.

here is the publishJoints.cpp code

```
#include <string>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GestureFile.h"
#define DOF 19
#define DIR_mt4      1
#define DIR_ma14     1
#define DIR_ma12     1
#define COUNT_DEG   2222    //encoder count per deg

 
enum parts
{
    m3joint_mt4_j0,
    m3joint_mt4_j1,
    m3joint_slave_mt4_j2,
    left_shoulder_pan_joint,
    left_shoulder_lift_joint,
    left_elbow_pan_joint,
    left_elbow_lift_joint,             
    m3joint_ma14_j4,
    m3joint_ma14_j5,
    m3joint_ma14_j6,
    right_shoulder_pan_joint,
    right_shoulder_lift_joint,
    right_elbow_pan_joint,
    right_elbow_lift_joint,
    m3joint_ma12_j4,
    m3joint_ma12_j5,
    m3joint_ma12_j6,
    Neck_Casing,
    Head_Casing,
            
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "publishJoints");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher joint_pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::JointState>("joint_states", 100);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(100000);

    const double degree = M_PI/180;

    // robot state
    double swivel=0;
    double tilt=0;


    // message declarations
    sensor_msgs::JointState joint_state;

   joint_state.name.resize(19);
   joint_state.position.resize(19);

   


    while (ros::ok()) {
        //update joint_state
        joint_state.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();

        swivel=0;
        joint_state.name[0] ="m3joint_mt4_j0";
        joint_state.position[0] = swivel;

        joint_state.name[1] ="m3joint_mt4_j1";
        joint_state.position[1] = swivel;

        joint_state.name[2] ="m3joint_slave_mt4_j2";
        joint_state.position[2] = tilt;

        joint_state.name[3] ="left_shoulder_pan_joint";
        joint_state.position[3] = tilt;

        joint_state.name[4] ="left_shoulder_lift_joint";
        joint_state.position[4] = tilt;

        joint_state.name[5] ="left_elbow_pan_joint";
        joint_state.position[5] = tilt;

        joint_state.name[6] ="left_elbow_lift_joint";
        joint_state.position[6] = tilt;

        joint_state.name[7] ="m3joint_ma14_j4";
        joint_state.position[7] = swivel;

        joint_state.name[8] ="m3joint_ma14_j5";
        joint_state.position[8] = swivel;

        joint_state.name[9] ="m3joint_ma14_j6";
        joint_state.position[9] = swivel;

        joint_state.name[10] ="right_shoulder_pan_joint";
        joint_state.position[10] = swivel;

        joint_state.name[11] ="right_shoulder_lift_joint";
        joint_state.position[11] = swivel;

        joint_state.name[12] ="right_elbow_pan_joint";
        joint_state.position[12] = swivel;

        joint_state.name[13] ="right_elbow_lift_joint";
        joint_state.position[13] = swivel;

        joint_state.name[14] ="m3joint_ma12_j4";
        joint_state.position[14] = tilt;

        joint_state.name[15] ="m3joint_ma12_j5";
        joint_state.position[15] = tilt;

        joint_state.name[16] ="m3joint_ma12_j6" ;
        joint_state.position[16] = tilt;

        joint_state.name[17] ="Neck_Casing" ;
        joint_state.position[17] = tilt;

        joint_state.name[18] ="Head_Casing" ;
        joint_state.position[18] = tilt;

    
    tilt += 0.000001;
    

        //send the joint state and transform
        joint_pub.publish(joint_state);

        // This will adjust as needed per iteration
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }




    return 0;
}

int readDynamicGestureFile(points_body_t gesture[][10000], int *numOfCoords)
{
    int number=0;
    char buff[500];
    double position[DOF]={0};
    int time;
    FILE* ifp=NULL;

    //there is only one file to read
    memset(&buff,0,sizeof(buff));

    if ( fopen_s(&ifp, "C://share/Motion.csv","r") != 0 )
    {
        AfxMessageBox( "Cannot open Motion File that was sent");
        return 0;
    }
    
    do {
            fgets(buff,500,ifp);

            int result = sscanf_s(buff, "%d %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf  %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf %*c %lf",
                &time,
                &position[0],   //m3joint_mt4_j0
                &position[1],   //m3joint_mt4_j1
                &position[2],   //m3joint_slave_mt4_j2
                &position[3],   //left_shoulder_pan_joint
                &position[4],   //left_shoulder_lift_joint

                &position[5],   //left_elbow_pan_joint
                &position[6], //left_elbow_lift_joint             
                &position[7],   //m3joint_ma14_j4
                &position[8],   //m3joint_ma14_j5
                &position[9],   //m3joint_ma14_j6
                &position[10], //right_shoulder_pan_joint
                &position[11], //right_shoulder_lift_joint

                &position[12],  //right_elbow_pan_joint
                &position[13],  //right_elbow_lift_joint
                &position[14],  //m3joint_ma12_j4
                &position[15],  //m3joint_ma12_j5
                &position[16],  //m3joint_ma12_j6
                &position[17],  //Neck_Casing
                &position[18]   //Head_Casing
            
            );  
                
            //*********************//
            //  Conversion Matrix  //
            //*********************//
            
            gesture[0][number].m3joint_mt4_j0   = (int)( 0 );
            //gesture[0][number].ptorso_1   = (int)( DIR_T1 * -position[1] );
            gesture[0][number].m3joint_mt4_j1   = (int)( 0 );

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////       
            gesture[0][number].m3joint_slave_mt4_j2     = (int)( DIR_mt4 * COUNT_DEG * (-position[2]) );
            gesture[0][number].left_shoulder_pan_joint  = (int)( DIR_ma14 * COUNT_DEG * -position[3] );
            gesture[0][number].left_shoulder_lift_joint     = (int)( DIR_ma14 * COUNT_DEG * position[4] );

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            gesture[0][number].left_elbow_pan_joint   = (int)(  DIR_ma14 * COUNT_DEG * (position[5] + 90 ) );
            gesture[0][number].left_elbow_lift_joint  = (int)(  DIR_ma14 * COUNT_DEG * position[6] );
            gesture[0][number].m3joint_ma14_j4        = (int)(  DIR_ma14 * COUNT_DEG * ( -position[7] -90) );

            gesture[0][number].m3joint_ma14_j5              = (int)( COUNT_DEG * -position[8] );
            gesture[0][number].m3joint_ma14_j6              = (int)( COUNT_DEG * -position[9] );
            gesture[0][number].right_shoulder_pan_joint         = (int)( COUNT_DEG * -position[10] );
            //gesture[0][number].right_shoulder_lift_joint = (int)( COUNT_DEG * position[11] );

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            gesture[0][number].right_elbow_pan_joint      = (int)(  COUNT_DEG * ( -position[12] - 90 ) );
            gesture[0][number].right_elbow_lift_joint     = (int)(  COUNT_DEG * position[13] );
            //gesture[0][number].pR_upper_2 = (int)( COUNT_DEG * ( 90-position[R_upper_2] ) );
            gesture[0][number].m3joint_ma12_j4            = (int)(  COUNT_DEG * ( -position[14] + 90 ) );

            gesture[0][number].m3joint_ma12_j5= (int)( COUNT_DEG * -position[15] );
            gesture[0][number].m3joint_ma12_j6= (int)( COUNT_DEG * -position[16] );
            gesture[0][number].Neck_Casing = (int)( COUNT_DEG * -position[17] );
            gesture[0][number].Head_Casing = (int)( COUNT_DEG * position[18] );

            number++;

        } while(!feof(ifp));

    numOfCoords[0] = number;
    fclose(ifp);

    return 1;

}
```

following are the error messages when i compile.

```
error: ‘fopen_s’ was not declared in this scope

error: ‘AfxMessageBox’ was not declared in this scope

error: ‘sscanf_s’ was not declared in this scope
```

anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10430/error:-____-was-not-declared-in-this-scope/) by [ram](https://answers.ros.org/users/641/ram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2011-06-28

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you tagged the question linux, I assume you are not working on windows.
fopen_s, sscanf_s, AfxMessageBox are all windows specific functions.

You will need the linux variants as fopen and sscanf. For errors use ROS_ERROR or ROS_FATAL.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1